# Dataframe Pandas aggregation and/or groupby

Tags: python-3.x, group-by, pandas-groupby, aggregation

I have a dataframe like this:

```
serie  = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
values = [2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]

series_X_values = {'series': serie, 'values': values}

df_mytest = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(series_X_values)
df_mytest
```

I need to create a third column (for example more frequently)

```
df_mytest['most_frequent'] = np.nan
```

whose values will be the most frequently observed in the 'values' column grouped by 'series', or replace the values in the 'values' column with the most frequent term itself as in the dataframe below:

```
serie  = [1, 2, 3]
values = [2, 2, 1]

series_X_values = {'series': serie, 'values': values}

df_mytest = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(series_X_values)
df_mytest
```

I tried some unsuccessful options like:

```
def personal_most_frequent(col_name):
  from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
  imp = SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")

  return imp

df_result = df_mytest.groupby('series').apply(personal_most_frequent('values'))
```

but...

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py
>   in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
>       688             try:
>   --> 689                 result = self._python_apply_general(f)
>       690             except Exception:
>
> 5 frames
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py
>   in _python_apply_general(self, f)
>       706         keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, self._selected_obj,
>   --> 707                                                    self.axis)
>       708
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py in
>   apply(self, f, data, axis)
>       189             group_axes = _get_axes(group)
>   --> 190             res = f(group)
>       191             if not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes):
>
> TypeError: 'SimpleImputer' object is not callable
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         5   return imp
>         6 
>   ----> 7 df_result = df_mytest.groupby('series').apply(personal_most_frequent('values'))
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py
>   in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
>       699 
>       700                 with _group_selection_context(self):
>   --> 701                     return self._python_apply_general(f)
>       702 
>       703         return result
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py
>   in _python_apply_general(self, f)
>       705     def _python_apply_general(self, f):
>       706         keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, self._selected_obj,
>   --> 707                                                    self.axis)
>       708 
>       709         return self._wrap_applied_output(
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py in
>   apply(self, f, data, axis)
>       188             # group might be modified
>       189             group_axes = _get_axes(group)
>   --> 190             res = f(group)
>       191             if not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes):
>       192                 mutated = True
>
> TypeError: 'SimpleImputer' object is not callable

and...

```
df_mytest.groupby(['series', 'values']).agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0])
```

but again...

> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py in
>   agg_series(self, obj, func)
>       589         try:
>   --> 590             return self._aggregate_series_fast(obj, func)
>       591         except Exception:
>
> 12 frames pandas/_libs/reduction.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.reduction.SeriesGrouper.get_result()
>
> pandas/_libs/reduction.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.reduction.SeriesGrouper.get_result()
>
> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in
>   **getitem**(self, key)    3956         if is_scalar(key):    3957             key = com.cast_scalar_indexer(key)
>   -> 3958             return getitem(key)    3959     3960         if isinstance(key, slice):
>
> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

I ask for help from the community to complete this process.

Comment: How should this behave in the case of series 2 where the values 1 and 2 have the same counts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are OK with tie-breaking equally represented values by taking the max value, you could do something like:

```
df_mf = df_mytest.groupby('series')['values'].apply(lambda ds: ds.mode().max()).to_frame('most_frequent')

df_mytest.merge(df_mf, 'left', left_on='series', right_index=True)
```

Out:

```
    series  values  most_frequent
0        1       2              2
1        1       2              2
2        1       2              2
3        1       1              2
4        2       2              2
5        2       2              2
6        2       1              2
7        2       1              2
8        3       1              1
9        3       1              1
10       3       1              1
11       3       2              1
```